# Is it possible using a UIPanGestureRecognizer to drag a top view to the right to expose a sub-view

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I need to drag my to view about 2/3 part of a screen width to the right to expose a sub-view (containing a tableview) and then drag it back after inter-acting with the tableview.

The `UIPanGestureRecognizer` seems to be what I need but after reading Apple's documentation I can't figure out the code needed in swift.

So to clarify - I have a view for capturing user data and I have a `tableview` that contains telephone labels and numbers - I want to be able to drag the user view, expose the table and then drag the user view back.

```
@IBAction func panPiece(_ gestureRecognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    // Move the anchor point of the view's layer to the touch point
    // so that moving the view becomes simpler.
    let piece = gestureRecognizer.view
    self.adjustAnchorPoint(gestureRecognizer: gestureRecognizer)

    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began || gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {
        // Get the distance moved since the last call to this method.
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: piece?.superview)

        // Set the translation point to zero so that the translation distance
        // is only the change since the last call to this method.
        piece?.center = CGPoint(x: ((piece?.center.x)! + translation.x),
                                y: ((piece?.center.y)! + translation.y))
        gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: piece?.superview)
    }
}
func adjustAnchorPoint(gestureRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {
        let view = gestureRecognizer.view
        let locationInView = gestureRecognizer.location(in: view)
        let locationInSuperview = gestureRecognizer.location(in: view?.superview)

        // Move the anchor point to the touch point and change the position of the view
        view?.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: (locationInView.x / (view?.bounds.size.width)!),
                                          y: (locationInView.y / (view?.bounds.size.height)!))
        view?.center = locationInSuperview
    }
}
```

Comment: are you able to pan the views or you are stuck writing pan logic?

Comment: I have only got as far as dragging one in to the "sourceView" and linking it to an action in the VC. 
I have partially achieved my goal by using presentationController and modal segues however the "drag" concept would work better for me than button pressing.
So yes this is the first time I have tried gestures and am stuck on the logic.

Comment: Add some tried code

Comment: Done code in original question\

Comment: func panPiece(_ gestureRecognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer) is your pan gesture's target method?

Comment: Code as per Apple yes it is  - I however think that to get the drag across idea going will require a custom gesture which at this stage is beyond my capabilities. (The kbaq app is a good example of what I want to achieve)  So for now will use the presentationController, but thanks for the interest.
If I find a solution I will post it.

Answer (score 1):

For attaching a gesture with a view

```
 let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(handlePanGesture))
 @objc private func handlePanGesture(sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer)
 {
     var translation = sender.translation(in: self)
     sender.view?.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: sender.view!)
     sender.view?.center = CGPoint(x: (sender.view?.center.x)! + translation.x , y : (sender.view?.center.y)! + translation.y)
     sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self)
 }
```

Comment: Worked fine except I need to stop any y movement

Comment: sender.view?.center = CGPoint(x: (sender.view?.center.x)! + translation.x , y : (sender.view?.center.y)! )      Modify this line of code and it will stop y movement. You don't change the y value of centre point.

Comment: Thanks will try this